# Moodle Forum notifctions

Tags: php, cron, moodle, execution, forum

This is my first question on this site.

I was told this would be the best way to find an answer.

I have a moodle install that seems to run ok but I am not able to receive any forum notifictions. I have been digging around quite a bit and I think (with my limited knowledge of developing) it may have something to do with the cron job.

I have set up a cron job for every minute as moodle instructs, but when I run scheduled tasks I get this message **Exception - Call to undefined method quiz_statistics\task\recalculate::set_last_run_time()**

I have another moodle site that works well and know problems, I was wondering if any experts on here may be able to assist?

Thank you in advance.

Howard

Set up moodle site
set up cron job schedule on hostinger panel
unable to get forum notifcations
get this message Exception - Call to undefined method quiz_statistics\task\recalculate::set_last_run_time()

Comment: Did you upgrade recently? Which version of Moodle are you using? Looks like some people had issues when upgrading - see https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=451237